# change hh:mm into decimal hh.mm (see example)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vba

In cell B239, I have 37:15 which represent the total number of hours it took someone to complete a task. 
In cell C239 I have the following formula

=INT(B239)*24+HOUR(B239)+ROUND(MINUTE(B239)/60,2)

which gives me 37.25 that is 37 hours and a quarter of 100. I am happy with this result and it does what I am looking for. However, in B241 I have 24:00 which should technically return 24.00 but it returns 0 in cell C241 instead.

It is as if 24:00 is recognised as midnight rather than 24 hours.

Note that the format of B239 and C239 is [h]:mm. B241 and C241 format is general.

Many thanks for your assistance
Abe

Comment: I have tried =text(B239, "[hh].mm") which is slightly different than yours. it does not do everything I need since it returns 37.15 instead of 37.25

Comment: simply try to change the cell default number format... if it shows 0 then your suggestion is correct, but if it shows 1 then the answer of "Scott Craner" should do exactly what you need...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TEXT(B239*24,"00.00")
```

on 24:00 it will return 24.00

[image]

As @ Darren Bartrup-Cook mentioned this will be a text field so any reference using this needs to convert it to a number.  There are many ways to do this.

You can us the double negative on the result, lets assume the result of the above formula is in C239:

```
=--C239
```

But ultimately the best method to do what you want is to format the cell in which you want the value as "General" with two decimal places then the whole thing can be done with one formula:

```
=Round(B239 * 24,2)
```

This will return a number and not a text with the correct formatting.

Comment: As an extra - that number is formatted as text which isn't generally a problem unless you're looking for a number with something like `=VLOOKUP(24.25,$B$1:$C$23,2,FALSE)` - it will return #N/A.  If needed wrap the TEXT function with a VALUE: `=VALUE(TEXT(A1*24,"00.00"))`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook added your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thank you. That's a very important point.